# Poll a drive location in web methods to see if a file has been upload from the mainframe?

Tags: webmethods

I am just starting out with WEBMethods. I am starting on a project that will need to poll a drive on my companies M: drive location. The file will arrive randomly from the mainframe and I will need to have WEBMethods some how pulled the file from the drive location.

Once I have to move the file from one location to another before I start my parsing of the file.

If I had more code I would post it, but WEBMethods is new and so far I actually have not writen any code in WEBMethods but I am extremely code with Java.

Drive location:

```
   M:\tempTest\NewDriveLocation\ThisIsTheFileINeed
```

I need to be able to have a transform that pulls in a file from any directly location on Friday. I have an input retieve on my MAP but have not figured out how to enter the file path so that it can find the file.

[image]

Comment: I would take one string FileName argument in my method, and then search within M:\Folder all files matching that FileName. What Technology are you using? That will determine how you fetch the files.

Comment: We are using WEBMethods. There are public transforms that can be used to perfrom different tasks such as date, time but there is several that I think might be able to be used for finding a file.

Comment: Ah see. I think you have the wrong WebMethod tag, and I think you are talking about WEBMethods as in the Software itself. Maybe the tag you want is WebMethods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webmethods

Comment: Yes you would be correct. I will see if I can change that tag line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Software AG](http://www.softwareag.com/)'s [webMethods Integration Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebMethods_Integration_Server) has a built-in feature called a File Polling Port, which you can configure to monitor a local or network shared directory for new files. The [Integration Server Administrator's Guide](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Integration_Server/9-5-SP1_Integration_Server_Administrators_Guide.pdf) instructions for how to set up a File Polling Port are as follows:

> A file polling port periodically polls a monitoring directory for the arrival of files and
> then performs special processing on them. When it detects a new file, the server copies
> the file to a working directory, then runs a special file processing service against the file.
> The service might parse, convert, and validate the file then write it to the file system. This
> service, which you write, is the only service that can be invoked through this port. You
> can limit the files the server accepts by filtering for specific file names.
>
> For file polling to work, you must do the following:
>
> 1. Set up the Monitoring Directory on Integration Server. Other directories used for file
>    polling are automatically created by Integration Server.
> 2. Write a file processing service and make it available to Integration Server. See
>    [webMethods Service Development Help](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Designer/9-5-SP1_Service_Development_Help.pdf) and the [Flat File Schema Developer's Guide](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Integration_Server/9-5-SP1_Flat_File_Schema_Developers_Guide.pdf) for
>    examples of such services.
> 3. Set up the file polling port on Integration Server.
>
> Use the following procedure to add a file polling port to Integration Server.
>
> 1. Open Integration Server Administrator if it is not already open.
> 2. In the Security menu of the Navigation panel, click Ports.
> 3. Click Add Port.
> 4. In the Add Port area of the screen, select webMethods/FilePolling.
> 5. Click Submit. Integration Server Administrator displays a screen requesting
>    information about the port.
> 6. Under Package, enter the following information:
>
>    - Package Name - The package associated with this port.
>      When you enable the package, the server enables the port.
>      When you disable the package, the server disables the port.
>
>      If you are performing special file handling, specify the
>      package that contains the services that perform that
>      processing. If you want to process flat files from this port,
>      select WmFlatFile,which contains built-in services you can
>      use to process flat files.
>
>      Note: If you replicate this package, whether to a server on
>      the same machine or a server on a separate machine, a file
>      polling port with the same settings is created on the target
>      server. If a file polling port already exists on the target
>      server, its settings remain intact. If the original and target
>      servers reside on the same machine, they will share the
>      same monitoring directory. If the target server resides on
>      another machine, by default, another monitoring directory
>      will be created on the target server's machine.
>    - Alias - An alias for the port. An alias must be between 1 and 255
>      characters in length and include one or more of the
>      following: ASCII characters, numbers, underscore (_),
>      period (.), and hyphen (-).
>    - Description - A description of the port.
> 7. Under Polling Information, enter the following information:
>
>    - Monitoring Directory - Directory on Integration Server that you want to
>      monitor for files.
>    - Working Directory (optional) - Directory on Integration Server to which the server
>      should move files for processing after they have been
>      identified in the Monitoring Directory. Files must meet
>      age and file name requirements before being moved to
>      the Working Directory. The default sub-directory,
>      MonitoringDirectory..\Work, is automatically created
>      if no directory is specified.\
>    - Completion Directory (optional) - Directory on Integration Server to which you want files
>      moved when processing is completed in the Monitoring
>      Directory or Working Directory. The default sub-directory,
>      MonitoringDirectory..\Done, is automatically created
>      if no directory is specified.
>    - Error Directory (optional) - Directory on Integration Server to which you want files
>      moved when processing fails. The default subdirectory,
>      MonitoringDirectory..\Error, is
>      automatically created if no directory is specified.
>    - File Name Filter (optional) - The file name filter for files in the Monitoring Directory.
>      The server only processes files that meet the filter
>      requirements. If you do not specify this field, all files
>      will be polled. You can specify pattern matching in this
>      field.
>    - File Age (optional) - The minimum age (in seconds) at which a file in the
>      Monitoring Directory can be processed. The server
>      determines file age based on when the file was last
>      modified on the monitoring directory. You can adjust
>      this age as needed to make sure the server does not
>      process a file before the entire file has been copied to
>      the Monitoring Directory. The default is 0.
>    - Content Type - Content type to use for the file. The server uses the
>      content handler associated with the content type
>      specified in this field. If no value is specified, the server
>      performs MIME mapping based on the file extension.
>    - Allow Recursive Polling - Whether Integration Server is to poll all sub-directories
>      in the Monitoring Directory. Select Yes or No.
>      Enable Clustering Whether Integration Server should allow clustering in
>      the Monitoring Directory. Select Yes or No.
>    - Number of files to process per interval (optional) -
>      Specifies the maximum number of files that the file
>      polling listener can process per interval. When you
>      specify a positive integer, the file polling listener
>      processes only that number of files from the
>      monitoring directory. Any files that remain in the
>      monitoring directory will be processed during
>      subsequent intervals. If no value is specified, the
>      listener processes all of the files in the monitoring
>      directory.
> 8. Under Security, in the Run services as user parameter, specify the user name you want
>    to use to run the services assigned to the file polling directory. Click to lookup and
>    select a user. The user can be an internal or external user.
> 9. Under Message Processing, supply the following information:
>
>    - Enable - Whether to enable (Yes) or disable (No) this file polling
>      port.
>    - Processing Service - Name of the service you want Integration Server to
>      execute for polled files. The server executes this service
>      when the file has been copied to the Working directory.
>      This service should be the only service available from
>      this port.
>
>      Important! If you change the processing service for a file
>      polling port, you must also change the list of services
>      available from this port to contain just the new service.
>      See below for more information.
>    - File Polling Interval - How often (in seconds) you want Integration Server to
>      poll the Monitoring Directory for files.
>    - Log Only When Directory Availability Changes -
>      If you select No (the default), the listener will log a
>      message every time the monitoring directory is
>      unavailable.
>
>      If you select Yes, the listener will log a message in
>      either of the following cases:
>
>      - The directory was available during the last polling
>        attempt but not available during the current
>        attempt
>      - The directory was not available during the last
>        polling attempt but is available during the current
>        attempt
>    - Directories are an NFS Mounted File System - For use on a UNIX system where the monitoring
>      directory, working directory, completion directory,
>      and/or error directory are network drives mounted on
>      the local file system.
>
>      If you select No (the default), the listener will call the
>      Java File.renameTo() method to move the files from the
>      monitoring directory to the working directory, and
>      from the working directory to the completion and/or
>      error directory.
>
>      If you select Yes, the listener will first call the Java
>      File.renameTo() method to move the files from the
>      monitoring directory. If this method fails, the listener
>      will then copy the files from the monitoring directory
>      to the working directory and delete the files from the
>      monitoring directory. This operation will fail if either
>      the copy action or the delete action fails. The same
>      behavior applies when moving files from the working
>      directory to the completion and/or error directory.
>    - Cleanup Service (Optional) - The name of the service that you want to use to clean
>      up the directories specified under Polling Information.
>    - Cleanup At Startup - Whether to clean up files that are located in the
>      Completion Directory and Error Directory when the file
>      polling port is started.
>    - Cleanup File Age (Optional) - The number of days to wait before deleting processed
>      files from your directories. The default is 7 days.
>    - Cleanup Interval (Optional) - How often (in hours) you want Integration Server to
>      check the processed files for cleanup. The default is 24
>      hours
>    - Maximum Number of Invocation Threads -
>      The number of threads you want Integration Server to
>      use for this port. Type a number from 1-10. The default
>      is 10.
> 10. Click Save Changes.
> 11. Make sure the port's access mode is properly set and that the file processing service is
>     the only service accessible from the port.
>
>     - In the Ports screen, click Edit in the Access Mode field for the port you just created.
>     - Click Set Access Mode to Deny by Default.
>     - Click Add Folders and Services to Allow List.
>     - Type the name of the processing service for this port in the text box under Enter
>       one folder or service per line.
>     - Remove any other services from the allow list.
>     - Click Save Additions.
>
>       Note: If you change the processing service for a file polling port, remember to
>       change the Allow List for the port as well. Follow the procedure described above
>       to alter the allowed service list.
>     - If you change the processing service for a file polling port, remember to change
>       the Allow List for the port as well. Follow the procedure described above to alter
>       the allowed service list.

The Processing Service referenced above is a service which you must develop.

If you are processing XML files with the File Polling Port, the file will be parsed prior to invoking your service, so you should create a service which has a single input argument of type object called `node` (which is the parsed XML document). You can then use the pub.xml services in the WmPublic package (such as `pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument` to convert the `node` to an IData document) to process the provided `node` object. Refer to the [Integration Server Built-In Services Reference](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Integration_Server/9-5-SP1_Integration_Server_Built-In_Services_Reference.pdf) for details on the pub.xml services.

If you are processing flat files (which is anything other than XML in webMethods), the File Polling Port will invoke your service with a java.io.InputStream object from which you can read the file contents, so you should create a service which has a single input argument of type object called `ffdata`. You can then use the pub.io services in the WmPublic package (such as `pub.io:streamToBytes` to read all data in the stream to a byte array) or the pub.flatFile services in the WmFlatFile package (such as `pub.flatFile:convertToValues` to convert `ffdata` to an IData document) to process the provided `ffdata` object. Refer to the [Integration Server Built-In Services Reference](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Integration_Server/9-5-SP1_Integration_Server_Built-In_Services_Reference.pdf) for details on the pub.io services, and the [Flat File Schema Developer's Guide](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-5_sp1/Integration_Server/9-5-SP1_Flat_File_Schema_Developers_Guide.pdf) for details on the pub.flatFile services.

If both XML and flat files are being written to the monitored directory, you can either write a service which optionally accepts both a `node` and `ffdata` object and check which one exists in the pipeline at runtime and process accordingly, or you can create two File Polling Ports which monitor the same directory but check for different file extensions (ie. *.xml and *.txt respectively) using the File Name Filter setting on the port.

If you want to poll a Windows file share, you can specify the directory using a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC_in_Windows) file path (such as `\\server\directory`) on the File Polling Port.

Also, you need to make sure the user account under which Integration Server executes has appropriate file access rights to the various directories configured on the File Polling Port.